# In Jupyter, how to position a code cell relative to an indented text in the Markdown cell above it?

Tags: jupyter

I have a set of hierarchical bullet lists in Markdown cells and would like to insert code cells positioned relative to the respective bullet points. How can this be achieved? In case it matters, I am primarily interested in solutions that work for Jupyter notebooks run on Jupyterhub using a Python 3 kernel.

The lists look similar to the sketch below, and I would like to change the next code cells' left margin from the default position indicated in red to something horizontally closer to the green or yellow locations.

- List item 1
- List item 2

  - List item 2a

    - List item 2a.1

Answer (score 1):

I think making a runnable code in that position is not possible

But inside markdown, you can put non-interactive python code

By using triple backtick ```python

and at the end put another triple backtick ```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that but want to show both code and results. My workaround for the moment is to create a GIF file showing the computation and then embed that GIF in the Markdown cell where I want it.

Comment: Gif is a fantastic idea.